# SQL group by current timestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have service requests in the database. I need to know how many of them were opened / closed for last 2 weeks grouped by days.

I have this query:

```
SELECT RIGHT('00'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(MONTH, OPENTIME)), 2) 
       + '-' 
       + RIGHT('00'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(DAY, OPENTIME)), 2) AS 'Day', 
       COUNT(OPENTIME)                                               AS 
       'Count of Opened', 
       COUNT(CLOSETIME)                                              AS 
       'Count of Closed' 
FROM   JEZD.F_SERVICE_REQUESTS 
WHERE  OPENTIME >= DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, 
                                DATEADD(D, -14, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)), 0 
                   ) 
GROUP  BY RIGHT('00'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(MONTH, OPENTIME)), 2) 
          + '-' 
          + RIGHT('00'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(DAY, OPENTIME)), 2)
```

This is being grouped by OpenTime so e.g. today was no service requested opened, this SQL wont count any closed tickets until some new is opened. I have tried to modify the where clause and group clause from OpenTime to Current_Time, but I am getting error `Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.` Do you have any workaround for this?

Dataset as of now:

```
Day     Opened Closed
09-30   29   21
10-02   23   18
09-27   27   25
10-03   16   12
10-01   59   44
09-26   23   18
10-04   31   20
09-25   35   29
10-07   22   12
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd perform:

1. Query for Opened Requests in last 14 days
2. Query for Closed Request in last 14 days
3. Full join the two on date

Comment: Yes, I have it like this using union. However, I was looking for some other solution. Thanks for your reply though!